# session method cannot be called 2 times in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, twilio

In the code below, when the #call method executes, it redirects the call to the #connect method to play an audio, then the #connect method redirects to #menu_selection where everything breaks. the error I get in heroku logs is that sessions is nil or defined.

What I dont understand is that I am already using session[:user_id] in the first method #call. why is it no defined in the #menu_selection method?

```
    def call
      @list = User.find_by(id: session[:user_id]).contact_lists.find_by(id: session[:last_contact_list_id])
      @contacts = @list.contacts

      @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(@@account_sid, @@auth_token)
      @contacts.each do |contact|
        @call = @client.account.calls.create(
          :from => '+18056234397',   # From your Twilio number
          :to => '+1' + contact.phone ,     # To any number

          :url => root_url + "connect"
        )
      end
      redirect_to root_path
    end



  def connect
    response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
      r.Play 'https://clyp.it/l1qz52x5.mp3'
      r.Gather numDigits: '1', action: menu_path do |g|
        g.Play 'https://a.clyp.it/2mue3ocn.mp3'
      end
    end
   render :xml => response.to_xml
 end



 def menu_selection
   list = User.find_by(id: session[:user_id]).contact_lists.find_by(id: session[:last_contact_list_id])
   user_selection = params[:Digits]
   @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(@@account_sid, @@auth_token)
   case user_selection
   when "1"
     @output = "say something."
     twiml_say(@output, true)
   when "2"
     twiml_dial("+1805XXXXX")
   when "3"
     @output = "Bye Bye..."
     twiml_say(@output, true)
  end
end
```

In the #menu_selection method I get the error : undefined local variable or method `session'

Its in the first line where I'm defining the "list" variable.

I never had this kind of issue before. If anyone knows whats going on, I would appreciate your help.

I tried defining the first @list variable as a class variable outside of the method #call but It gives me the same error that I get now. I also tried making it a class variable inside the #call method to try using it in #menu_selection method, but I get an "@@list is undefined" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The problem here is that the session in the `#call` action is between your user and the server. However, when you initiate a call and Twilio calls back to your server the session between Twilio and the server is completely different.

In this situation, you need to pass the data you need Twilio to know through your URL. So, instead of just sending the connect URL, send it with the parameters you need later. So your `#call` action would look like:

```
def call
  @list = User.find_by(id: session[:user_id]).contact_lists.find_by(id: session[:last_contact_list_id])
  @contacts = @list.contacts

  @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(@@account_sid, @@auth_token)
  @contacts.each do |contact|
    @call = @client.account.calls.create(
      :from => '+18056234397',   # From your Twilio number
      :to => '+1' + contact.phone ,     # To any number

      :url => root_url + "connect?user_id=#{session[:user_id]}&last_contact_list_id=#{session[:last_contact_list_id]}"
    )
  end
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Then, your `#connect` action will need to pass those on to your `#menu_selection` action too (note the `menu_path` line):

```
def connect
  response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    r.Play 'https://clyp.it/l1qz52x5.mp3'
    r.Gather numDigits: '1', action: menu_path(:user_id => params[:user_id], :last_contact_list_id => params[:last_contact_list_id] do |g|
      g.Play 'https://a.clyp.it/2mue3ocn.mp3'
    end
  end
  render :xml => response.to_xml
end
```

Finally, you will be able to use those parameters, instead of the session, in your `#menu_selection` action:

```
def menu_selection
  list = User.find_by(id: params[:user_id]).contact_lists.find_by(id: params[:last_contact_list_id])
  user_selection = params[:Digits]
  @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(@@account_sid, @@auth_token)
  case user_selection
  when "1"
    @output = "say something."
    twiml_say(@output, true)
  when "2"
    twiml_dial("+1805XXXXX")
  when "3"
    @output = "Bye Bye..."
    twiml_say(@output, true)
  end
end
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Philnash, thanks again for your help. This is the second time you answer a question for me. I really  appreciate it. I tried exactly as you suggested and it worked. :D

Comment: No problem! I'm just here to help :)

Comment: I appreciate it :) Do you know how I could hang up the call if the person receiving the call does not pick up? or is it possible? cause right now as it is, it leaves a voice message if they dont answer. It leaves the mp3 recording as a message.

Comment: Check out Twilio's answering machine detection: https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/can-twilio-tell-whether-a-call-was-answered-by-a-human-or-machine